# Reference Error: View is not defined

Tags: javascript, php

I am a beginner and i want to write this function. but when i try to run it, why view is not defined although i already defined it. Anyone can give me the solution for this problem? Here is the full source code

```
<?php
    include ("connection.php");
    session_start();
    $user_login = $_SESSION['user'];
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Messenger</title>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0\css\font-awesome.css">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
    <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function viewProfile($name){
        var name ='test';
        alert(name);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body class="blue">
<div id="chat-page">
    <div id="chatbox" class="row container">
    <?php
    $select = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username != '$user_login'");
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($select);
    //echo $row_1;
        if($row != 0){
            while($list= mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
            $name = $list['Username'];
            echo $name;
            $userFriend = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username = '$name'");
            $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userFriend);
            echo "<div class='friend'>";
            echo "<a href='#' onclick=\"viewProfile($name)\" style='text-decoration:none'>";
            if($fetch['Display Picture'])
                $pic = 'avatar.jpg';
            echo "<img src='".$pic."' alt='' class='circle responsive-img'>";
            echo "<p>";
            echo "<strong>".$fetch['Username']."</strong><br>";
            echo "<span>".$fetch['Email']."</span>";
            echo "</p>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</a>";
            }
        }else
        echo "username not found";
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please put the exact error log in your question body

Comment: Is `view()` inside any other handler function ?

Comment: Here is the error:
ReferenceError: view is not defined 
onclick

Comment: $name will have no value when it's outputting the <script> content, as it's assigned a value further down in the code.

Comment: if the <a onclick='viewProfile($name)'> it could be?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your **view()** function in script tags.Also put javascript at the bottom of the page.

Try **below code:**

```
<?php
echo "<div class='friend'>";
echo "<a href='#' onclick=\"view()\" style='text-decoration:none'>Click here </a>";
echo "</div>";
?>


<script>
    function view(){
        var name = 'Function Test';
        alert(name);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: if the <a onclick='viewProfile($name)'> it could be?

Comment: You can do that, you have to place argument/parameter i.e "viewProfile(name)" to receive the value in your javascript function  and then perform the logic on it as per requirement.

Comment: for the parameter in javascript, we should user $name or only name i.e "viewProfile(name)" or "viewProfile($name)"?

Comment: In javascript function "viewProfile(name){}" and "<a onclick="viewProfile($name)">".

Comment: I have code something like that:
<?php
$name = $list['username'];
echo "<a onclick="viewProfile($name)"></a>";
?>
<script>
function viewProfile(name){
alert(name);
}
</script>
Why it doens't work? can you give the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If function in php file then add `<script> // js code </script>`

Use like this :

```js
function view(){
    var name = 'Test';
    alert(name);
}
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick="view()" style='text-decoration:none'>Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your javascript at the bottom after php code, `$name` is not recognizing its existence, **PHP Always evaluated before javascript** and in your view function you have php variable `$name`

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
  function view(){
    var name = "<?php echo $name; ?>";
    alert(name);
  }
</script>
```